# How to find the similarity of sentences in 2 columns of a dataframe using spacy

Tags: python, pandas, spacy, similarity, bert-language-model

I pulled this code from https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacy-sentence-bert

```
import spacy_sentence_bert
# load one of the models listed at https://github.com/MartinoMensio/spacy-sentence-bert/
nlp = spacy_sentence_bert.load_model('en_roberta_large_nli_stsb_mean_tokens')
# get two documents
doc_1 = nlp('Hi there, how are you?')
doc_2 = nlp('Hello there, how are you doing today?')
# use the similarity method that is based on the vectors, on Doc, Span or Token
print(doc_1.similarity(doc_2[0:7]))
```

I have a dataframe with 2 columns containing sentences like below. I'm trying to find the similarity between the sentences in each row. I've tried a few different methods but not having much luck so figured I would ask here. Thank you all.

**Current df**

```
Sentence1 | Sentence2

Another-Sentence1 | Another-Sentence2

Yet-Another-Sentence1 | Yet-Another-Sentence2
```

**Goal output:**

```
Sentence1 | Sentence2 | Similarity-Score-Sentence1-Sentence2

Another-Sentence1 | Another-Sentence2 | Similarity-Score-Another-Sentence1-Another-Sentence2

Yet-Another-Sentence1 | Yet-Another-Sentence2 | Similarity-Score-Yet-Another-Sentence1-Yet-Another-Sentence2
```

Comment: Your data is stored in a list or in Excel table?

Comment: Originally a CSV and I'm parsing 2 of the columns into the dataframe.

Comment: Noted, I put my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your first row consists of headers, the data will start from the next row after header, and also assume that you are using panda to convert csv to dataframe, the below code works in my environment.

```
import spacy_sentence_bert
import pandas as pd
nlp = spacy_sentence_bert.load_model('en_roberta_large_nli_stsb_mean_tokens')
df = pd.read_csv('testing.csv')
similarityValue = []

for i in range(df.count()[0]):
    sentence_1 = nlp(df.iloc[i][0])
    sentence_2 = nlp(df.iloc[i][1])
    similarityValue.append(sentence_1.similarity(sentence_2))
    print(sentence_1, '|', sentence_2, '|', sentence_1.similarity(sentence_2))

df['Similarity'] = similarityValue
print(df)
```

Input CSV:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: "Hello" and "Hi" only 0.68 similarity score? Isn't that a bit low?

Comment: Yes it is since it is a pre-trained model from spacy, might need to customize for your own needs. These are just sample data for the main question.

Comment: No problem at all

Comment: @KeepLearning can I ask a quick followup? What if I wanted to add the similarity values back to the dataframe in column C, how would I do that?

Comment: @user1624562, I updated the code and output screenshot above by appending the similarity values to a list, then add the list to the dataframe,

Comment: BERT is not optimized for such tasks : https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/issues/80 .  STS Leaderboard and Open LLM Leaderboard on Hugging Face :  https://huggingface.co/spaces/mteb/leaderboard (may be helpful)

Comment: You may also want to look at `sentence-trandformers` (a python library based on huggingface `transformers`). It has models specifically pre-trained for the similarity task, and helpers such as `semantic_similarity` that you can use for needle/haystack type queries. You can probably integrate a sentence transformer model with spacy